# need to figure out T of class Repository is for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, repository-pattern

I have class Repository, and based on T i want to create objectset for the type T..in my constructor...this is what i have so far..

```
public static class Repository<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
{
    private DeltaDBEntities context;
    private ObjectSet<T> objectset;
    public Repository()
    {
        this.context =  new DeltaDBEntities();
        switch
        {
            case T = typeof(ViewModels.Company):
                this.objectset = context.Companies;
                break;
        }

        this.objectset = context.Set
    }
```

Comment: I think you are using the repository pattern the wrong way. I think Greg Young wrote a good post in how you should use it here: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve and why are you using generics for something that is not known at compile time but you may try the following:

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    private DeltaDBEntities context;
    private ObjectSet<T> objectset;

    public Repository()
    {
        this.context = new DeltaDBEntities();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ViewModels.Company))
        {
            this.objectset = context.Companies;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ViewModels.SomeOtherClass))
        {
            this.objectset = context.SomethingElse;
        }
        else
        {
            this.objectset = context.Set;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO: implement IDisposable
    }
}
```

Also note that a static class cannot implement an interface so `Repository<T>` should not be static.

Comment: I want to create generic repository class and preform query and mapping for the type...am i making sense??

Comment: @WingMan20-10, no, I don't understand. If you are writing such ifs in a generic type based on T then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: What he's saying is he should be able to dynamically create an object set based on T. I've done this before - using the technique @frennky describes (CreateObjectSet)

Answer (score 1):

If your `DeltaDBEntities` inherits from `ObjectContext`, you can use its generic method `CreateObjectSet<T>()`.

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private DeltaDBEntities context;
    private ObjectSet<T> objectset;

    public Repository()
    {
        this.context = new DeltaDBEntities();
        this.objectset = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
}
```